# Django Database didn't migrate

Tags: python, mysql, django

I use Django 1.10

school/models.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False)
    school_id = models.CharField(max_length=8,null=False)
    weather = models.ForeignKey(Weather,related_name="school")
```

When I modified the school class by adding `eng_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)`

I deleted the migrations file first.

And after running the command:

`python manage.py makemigrations school`

`python manage.py migrate --fake-initial school`

`python manage.py migrate school`

The messages both for the `migrate` are

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: school
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

But the database didn't update.

What is the possible reason to cause this issue?

*UPDATAE*

migrations/0001_initial.py

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
    ('weather', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='School',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=10)),
            ('eng_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('school_id', models.CharField(max_length=8)),
            ('weather', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='school', to='weather.Weather')),
        ],
    ),
]
```

`python manage.py showmigrations --plan`

> [X]  weather.0001_initial
>
> [X]  school.0001_initial

These both are the latest migrate .

Comment: Can you show your migration file ?

Comment: is school added as an app to your settings.py file?

Comment: maybe you fake it, you have --list option to see if your migration files are applied or not  `python manage.py migrate --list`

Comment: Chris Hawkes yes

Comment: MD. Khairul Basar I have edited in the question

Comment: JuanMi Gabarron I have edited in the question

Comment: please check that your module `school` is in it INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: mexekanez yes I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is storing applied migrations in database as table (django_migrations) with columns (id, app, name, applied). Just remove row with applied initial migration for "school" app then make migrate. And, in future, do not remove old transactions files. With them django will create properly named transactions for migration-mechanism.

Comment: Finally,I created the column in Mysql server.Then corresponded successfully.